# How can I rotate my screen with OctoDash installed?

Tags: pi-4, touchscreen

I want to rotate the touchscreen on my Pi4 with Octoprint and OctoDash installed on to. I've opend the file /boot/config.txt and added the line "display_rotate=2", but nothing happend (yes I rebooted the pi). I couldn't find any answers. I dont thing thats important but its a 7" screen.

I hope anybody could help me, best regrats.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably way too late, but try lcd_rotate instead of display_rotate